# What does the meaning of "informed on you" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Context: Mr smith saying Janusz wife reveal information about Janusz to Russian soldiers. Irene told this to Mr.Smith.

> Irena told me that they tortured your wife and she **informed on you**.

I am familiar with **informed by me** in English sentences, But I never came across **informed on you**. so What does it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**inform on** (or **inform against**)](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/inform-on): to secretly give the police or someone in authority information about someone.

For example:

> Tommy would never have gone to jail if one of his crew hadn't **informed on him** to the cops

Another example:

> Before the end of the Cold War many in the country were afraid to speak their political views openly, for fear that their neighbors would **inform on them** to the secret police.

Note the difference between this and other combinations like "inform of" or "inform about", which are more innocuous.  It's a good idea to memorize English verb-preposition pairs individually, since together they can have a very different meaning from the verb by itself.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily the case that the information was **given** in secrecy, but that the information given was **supposed to remain secret**.